# Making Visual Studio UI smaller

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I am trying to make the UI of Visual Studio 2017 smaller, but I can't find any settings for that.

I know I can resize the code-content, but I am looking for a way to make the Solution Explorer, Properties, Toolbar, etc. smaller.

Comment: What do you mean by make smaller? you can resize each different section just as you can with the code content

Comment: @DarthTommy I am looking for something like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2013/09/10/visual-studio-2013-zooming-in-and-out-of-text-in-the-editor/ but for the rest of the UI, like smaller folder/file-names in solution explorer.

Comment: Lower width on scrollbar, and smaller icons for the panels

Comment: ok now I understand! see answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors
2. In "Show Settings for" chose "Environment"
3. In "Font" replace Automatic to a different font, then change the size.

Change the font size of that setting, all Font size in the Explorers (Solution Explorer, Server Explorer and Toolbox) and menus will change.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. New when I have made the font smaller, the line-height and padding is still the same, is it possible to change that too?

Comment: ive looked a bit and couldnt find anything related to that. if you find something, let me know

Comment: Cool, I will accept your answer. Thank you for your help:-)

Comment: the only other solution I can think of is changing your screen resolution. then from there you can make the font larger in VS. Thanks!